# Assign lists/values of rows to column names

Tags: python, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

This code used one hot encoding technique.

```
#For every row in the dataframe, iterate through the list of genres and place a 1 into the corresponding column
for index, row in movies_df.iterrows():
    for genre in row['genres']:
        moviesWithGenres_df.at[index, genre] = 1
#Filling in the NaN values with 0 to show that a movie doesn't have that column's genre
moviesWithGenres_df = moviesWithGenres_df.fillna(0)
moviesWithGenres_df.head()
```

I got the idea to go through each low of dataframe, and I understand that assign "1" to each genre column, but how to assign each genre from each row to a single column here?

As the results shows each Genere(comedy, advanture, romance) from each row become a new column to this dataframe. Thank you.

This is the output before above code (before)
[image]

This is the output after above code (after)

[image]

Comment: can you provide some data and expected output?

Comment: Thanks, It is  a question I asked several months ago, I will try to find the info back and post here.

Comment: I updated the question and add the output pics. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
moviesWithGenres_df.at[index, genre] = 1
```

this line assign value to dataframe at row = index , and column = genre
which genre is variable that keep string of genre (such as 'comedy')
so if columns not exist in dataframe it would create new one with the name same as parameter columns(which is genre that keep string of genre(such as 'comedy').

read this document : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html